# Changing position of points on the scatter plots on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using google charts and following is the script that is available on google.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
           <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>



 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Age', 'Weight'],
      [ 8,      12],
      [ 4,      5.5],
      [ 11,     14],
      [ 4,      5],
      [ 3,      3.5],
      [ 6.5,    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
      hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

What I want is that on mouse click when I click the position of the dots and change it to new location then that position gets updated on the chart and corresponding array values also gets updated.How to approach this sort of problem? only a generic idea would  suffice for me.

Comment: can you please clarify _click the position of the dots and change it to new location_...? are you wanting to click the point and drag it to a new location and update the data / chart accordingly?

Comment: yes 100% that is my requirement

Comment: to get the drag effect, you'll need to redraw the chart continuously. for a frame of reference, set min / max values on the axis and height / width of chart area, start things off with the `'select'` event, then calculate new value based on coordinates of the mouse.